# Alter table to add partition taking long time on Hive external table

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, hive, amazon-emr

I'm trying to execute a spark job through EMR cluster with 6 nodes(8 cores and 56GB memory on each node). Spark job does an incremental load on partitions on Hive table and at the end it does a refresh table in order to update the metadata.

Refresh command takes as long as 3-6 hours to complete which is too long.

**Nature of data in Hive:**

1. 27Gb of data located on S3.
2. Stored in parquet.
3. Partitioned on 2 columns.(ex: **s3a//bucket-name/table/partCol1=1/partCol2=2020-10-12**).

Note- Its a date wise partition and cannot be changed.

**Spark config used:**

- Num-executors= 15
- Executor-memory =16Gb
- Executor-cores = 2
- Driver-memory= 49Gb
- Spark-shuffle-partitions=48
- Hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict
- Spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode=dynamic.

**Things tried:**

- Tuning the spark cores/memory/executors but no luck.
- Refresh table command.
- Alter table add partition command.
- Hive cli taking 3-4 hours to complete `MSCK repair table tablename`

All the above had no effect on reducing the time to refresh the partition on Hive.

**Some assumptions:**

1. Am I missing any parameter in tuning as the data is stored in Amazon-S3.?
2. Currently number of partitions on table are close to 10k is this an issue.?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

- incase possible, make the partitions to 1 column. It kills when we have multi level (multi column partitions)
- use R type instance. It provides more memory compared to M type instances at same price
- use coalesce to merge the files in source if there are many small files.
- Check the number of mapper tasks. The more the task, lesser the performance
- use EMRFS rather than S3 to keep the metadata info
- use below

  {
  "Classification": "spark",
  "Properties": {
  "maximizeResourceAllocation": "true"
  }
  }
- Follow some of the instructions from below [Link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/best-practices-for-successfully-managing-memory-for-apache-spark-applications-on-amazon-emr/)